# Transforming $\tan{\phi} = c_1 \tan{\phi_1}+ c_2 \tan{\phi_2}$ into the form $\phi = d_1 \phi_1 + d_2 \phi_2$

Tags: trigonometry

my problem is that I am trying to transform this trigonometric expression:
$$\tan{\phi} = c_1 \tan{\phi_1}+ c_2 \tan{\phi_2}$$

to the form: $$\phi = d_1 \phi_1 + d_2 \phi_2$$

Note: Here $c_1$ = $\frac{\beta_1}{\beta_1+\beta_2}$ and $c_2$ = $\frac{\beta_2}{\beta_1+\beta_2}$

My basic aim is to represent $c_1$ as $f_1(d_1,d_2, \phi_1, \phi_2, \phi)$ and $c_2$ as $f_2(d_1,d_2, \phi_1, \phi_2, \phi)$ by comparing the coefficients. But the final form is necessary meaning that the comparison of coefficients is done only after the given form $d_1 \phi_1 + d_2 \phi_2$ is attained on the RHS.
I would be really grateful if someone could help me out with this. Also if someone could suggest someother method for this function estimation, that could also be of great help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're trying to find $c_{1,2}$ independent of $\phi_{1,2}$, you're out of luck.

Comment: No, $\phi_{1,2}$ dependance of the coefficients is fine. I just want this particular form. The coefficients $c_{1,2}$ can depend on anything. Sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: Then what kind of the dependency do you admit? What do you expect to get for $\phi_1 = \phi_2$, say? (Or even for $d_1 \phi_1 = d_2 \phi_2$.) Is it a hope for purely algebraic one?..

Comment: (Or you're satisfied with $c_1=\tan(d_1\phi_1 + d_2\phi_2)/\tan\phi_1$ and $c_2=0$, roughly speaking? ;)

Comment: (Once you get certain, please put the relevant conditions into the text of the question.)

Comment: Actually I already have the values of $d_1$ and $d_2$ and I want to find the values of $c_1$ and $c_2$ by coefficient comparison. So, there wont be cases where I put exact values in $\phi_{1,2}$ but I would compare their coefficient in the final expression and substitute them in place of the unknowns. So, $\phi_1=\phi_2$ wont arise as I would never put their exact values as that would rule out coefficient comparison. Hope I am able to make my target clear. It is just expression transformation and coefficient comparison problem.

Comment: Even $\phi = c_1 \frac{\phi / tan(\phi)}{\phi_1 / tan(\phi_1)}  * \phi_1+  c_2 \frac{\phi / tan(\phi)}{\phi_2 / tan(\phi_2)} * \phi_2$ could have been good enough for me as I could have directly equated each to $d_{1,2}$ and got the values of $c_{1,2}$ but here I am just getting the ratio of $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ and cant go for the exact values. Is there any way to get to the values??

Please see the edits made in the actual question for references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simplify the notation, let's write
$$
\tan z = a\tan x + b\tan y
$$

Then, for $-\pi / 2 < x,y < \pi/2$ we want to express $z$ as
$$
z(x,y) = \arctan (a\tan x + b\tan y) = f(x,y)x + g(x,y)y
$$
(we omit to indicate $a$ and $b$ among the variables of the functions).

As a first step, we have that
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  z(0,0) = 0 \hfill \cr 
  z(x,0) = \arctan (a\tan x) = f(x,0)x \hfill \cr 
  z(0,y) = \arctan (b\tan y) = g(0,y)y \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
Expanding into series
$$
\eqalign{
  & f(x,0)x = z(x,0) = \arctan (a\tan x) =   \cr 
  &  = ax - {a \over 3}\left( {a^{\,2}  - 1} \right)x^{\,3}  + O\left( {a^{\,5} x^{\,5} } \right)\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad f(x,0) = a - {a \over 3}\left( {a^{\,2}  - 1} \right)x^{\,2}  + O\left( {a^{\,5} x^{\,4} } \right)  \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad g(0,y) = b - {b \over 3}\left( {b^{\,2}  - 1} \right)y^{\,2}  + O\left( {b^{\,5} y^{\,4} } \right) \cr} 
$$

That hints to the fact that we can write
$$
\eqalign{
  & z(x,y) = \arctan (a\tan x + b\tan y) =   \cr 
  &  = ax + by + \left( {{{\arctan (a\tan x + b\tan y) - ax - by} \over {x + y}}} \right)\left( {x + y} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {{{\arctan (a\tan x + b\tan y) + \left( {a - b} \right)y} \over {x + y}}} \right)x +   \cr 
  &  + \left( {{{\arctan (a\tan x + b\tan y) + \left( {b - a} \right)x} \over {x + y}}} \right)y \cr} 
$$

Answer (score 1):

If i understand right, you can write

$$\frac{\tan(\phi_1)}{c_1^2+c_2^2}+\frac{c_2}{c_1^2+c_2^2}\tan(\phi_2)$$

Comment: Actually I just don't want the "tan" term. Rest everything is fine. I just want to express it as a linear combination of $\phi_{1,2}$